# How to setup cocos2dx for android on MacOs Lion?

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am trying to setup cocos2dx with eclipse on a MacOs Lion. I am following the tutorial below:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started

When I try and execute the ndk build shell tool i get the following error:

```
Davids-iMac:~ davidcavanagh$ /Users/davidcavanagh/Downloads/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-build ;    
exit;
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !    
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.    
/Users/davidcavanagh/Downloads/android-ndk-r8b/build/core/build-local.mk:130: *** Android   
NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
logout

[Process completed]
```

I have tried defining the NDK_PROJECT_PATH through the terminal by using

export NDK_PROJECT_PATH=/Users/davidcavanagh/Downloads/android-ndk-r8b/

This doesn't work. Can anyone help me as I have been stuck on this for ages. Is there a certain way of setting the path that I am not doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Re-read and re-read again his tutorial. You shouldn't be executing the ndk-build script without supplying the arguments it needs for building your project.

He mentions using the `create-android-project.sh` script inside the cocos2d-x directory. Make sure you do that, and follow the steps there where you'll supply the project name, reverse-domain application ID (e.g. com.company.project), and so on.  This will generate your project directory inside of the cocos2d-x directory, which you can easily & safely move to another location.

Once you have that project set up, you can import it into Eclipse, which, primarily, allows you to build the **Android project**, but does not refer to the C++ code directly. (You'd need to get CDT and the NDK plugin to actually hook your C++ code up inside of Eclipse).

Otherwise, what's worked for me so far is to run the `build_native.sh` script inside the project directory whenever I have new code that I want to test on my device.  This script references the `jni/Android.mk` file, where you need to specify your header paths and *.cpp files (similar to how you'd have to specify all of your implementation files with `g++` on the command line).

But before you do that, you need to make sure all the environment variables that `build_native.sh` uses are set up. You can either put them in your `~/.bashrc` file, or you can just stick them in that project directory (up to you. bashrc will make them available to all projects whenever you launch a new terminal, whereas hardcoding them into `build_native.sh` will only offer them to that specific project). I think all you need is to assign the full paths to NDK_ROOT, COCOS2DX_ROOT, and APP_ROOT, and `build_native.sh` should run successfully.

If you look down at the bottom of `build_native.sh`, you'll notice an invocation of `ndk-build`, along with all the necessary parameters that you were missing in your terminal session.